# Linq to get a list of models per Make into DTO

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a DTO class like this

```
public string Make { get; set; };
public List<string> Models { get; set; }
```

Then there is a table which contains a list of vehicles, with make and model columns.

My API endpoint accepts a list of strings (the Makes)

I need to return a list of the DTO class with each make and the list of models.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<MakeModelDTO>>> GetModelsByMakes([FromQuery] List<string> make_list)
{
return await _context.Vehicles.Where(x => x.Make.????).Select(x => x.Model).Distinct().ToListAsync();
}
```

I don't even want to show the code I've tried, because all versions turned out to be a mess.
I know this is suppose to be a very simple task, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `_context.Vehicles.Where(vehicle => makeList.Contains(vehicle.Make))` - will be converted to sql like `.. WHERE Make IN ('make1', 'make2', ..)`

Comment: Thanks Fabio - your solution got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly,** In condition you can do this

```
Where(x => make_list.Contains(x.Make)
```

or

```
Where(x => make_list.Any(m => m == x.Make)
```

**Secondly,** the method is returning `List<MakeModelDTO>`, So you should adjust select result like below

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Make).Select(g => 
               new MakeModelDTO { Make = g.Key,  Models = g.Select(p => p.Model).ToList() }).ToListAsync();
```

**FullCode**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<MakeModelDTO>>> GetModelsByMakes([FromQuery] List<string> make_list)
{
     return await _context.Vehicles.Where(x => make_list.Contains(x.Make)).GroupBy(p => p.Make).Select(g => 
               new MakeModelDTO { Make = g.Key,  Models = g.Select(p => p.Model).ToList() }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a much neater way than what I tried.

Comment: Yes, It's my pleasure.

Comment: .Select(v => v.Model)' could not be translated.

Comment: You mean `Models = g.Select(p => p.Model).ToList()`, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207730/discussion-between-phong-and-pieter-du-toit).

Answer (score 1):

As @Fabio suggested you can filter the make like that. Adding to it convert to your DTO you need to group by that also.

You could try something like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<MakeModelDTO>>> GetModelsByMakes([FromQuery] List<string> make_list)
{
       var resultAsDto = await _context.Vehicles
                        .Where(vehicle => makeList.Contains(vehicle.Make))
                        .GroupBy(v=>v.Make)
                        .Select(g=> new YourDto
                         {
                             Make= g.Key -- As it grouped by make
                             Models = g.Select(v=>v.Model)
                         }).ToListAsync()
        return resultAsDto 
}
```